# текст не располагается по центру

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
.navigation {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 99;
}
.menu {
 display: flex;
}
.menu li {
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.menu a {
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!-- start menu -->
   <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">ОБО МНЕ</a></li>
     <li><a href="portfolio.html">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">СВЯЗАТЬСЯ</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
<!-- end menu -->
```

текст никак не реагирует ниначто, кроме марджина. можно ли текст расположить по центру, оставив меню с position fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так что ли?

```
  * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      background: #000;
    }
    .navigation {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 40px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .menu li {
        list-style: none;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .menu a {
        position: relative;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 26px;
        margin-right: 75px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

При установки `position: fixed;` блок автоматически уменьшается до ширины контента.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}
.navigation {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 40px;
 position: fixed;
  width:100%;
 z-index: 99;
}
.menu {
  background:red;
 display: flex;
  
  justify-content:center;
}
.menu li {
 list-style: none;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
.menu a {
 position: relative;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 26px;
 margin-right: 75px;
}
```

```html
<!-- start menu -->
   <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">ОБО МНЕ</a></li>
     <li><a href="portfolio.html">ПОРТФОЛИО</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">СВЯЗАТЬСЯ</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
<!-- end menu -->
```